# Determining the source of an included symbol in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I am currently working on a project which forbids the inclusion of C++'s standard library.  One of the compiled files we are using lists the following symbol: 
`_Xran__Q2_3std12_String_baseCFv`

I believe this relates to standard library strings.  Am I incorrect in thinking so? If not, is anyone aware of an effective way of tracing the point at which this symbol was included?  A cursory search of the code base doesn't show anything obvious.

Comment: That looks kinda like a mangled name for something involving `std::_String_base`.  Before you go quoting me, though, know that i have no idea how VS mangles names.

Comment: Do you know which object file it's in and need to find which `#include` is responsible, or are you trying to find the object file?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310590/build-problem-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Maybe you can run the preprocessor over the files and then search the resulting output (`cl.exe /P`)

Comment: @Karl Both, unfortunately.  The issue is with a file I receive as a compiled library from a team member at a remote site.  I have a hackish way to narrow the field in a Unix environment, but am less familiar with kludgy Windows tricks.

Comment: `_Xran()` is a helper method in many VC class templates that throws a `std::out_of_range`. The mangled name seems to suggest that it comes from `std::basic_string` or a base class thereof.

Comment: After a bit of digging, it's indeed in `std::basic_string`. I don't understand how it gets mangled to `_String_base` though. What version of VS do you use?

Comment: @Xeo At the moment we are using VS2010.  I'd assumed it was related to the STL strings.  Appreciate the explanation, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be VC mangling, which always start with a question mark.

It does, however, fit the G++ mangling scheme, as is suggested by running

```
$ c++filt  --format=gnu "_Xran__Q2_3std12_String_baseCFv"
std::_String_base::_Xran( const(void))
```

What's weird is that `_Xran` seems to be part of VC's implementation for `std::string`.

Anyway, the header you're looking for is probably `#include <string>`.

**EDIT:** As a result of c++filt's output - are you sure it is compiled in VC++ ?

Comment: Given that most C++ standard library implementations borrow a large amount from the original SGI version of STL, it's not really so surprising to find the same name `_Xran` in both VC and C++.

Comment: Afraid I don't recognize the VC acronym.  Can you clarify?

Comment: VC = Visual C/C++; the C++ compiler in the Visual Studio package.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I quite agree that we are looking for the string library.  Given that, I'm checking the include during compilation for hints.

Comment: Confirmed.  The author is indeed compiling in VC++, version 2010

Answer (score 0):

In case string.h is indeed included at some place, you can find out where:

Place in the next line after every `#include` directive the following code:

```
using namespace std;class string;struct{void hxtestfunc(void){typedef string hxtesttype;}};
```

When compiling, this will generate an "ambiguous symbol" error only if string.h (or any file that includes string.h directly or indirectly) was included somewhere before.

So the first reported "ambiguous symbol" error will lead you to the line right after the critical inclusion.

In Visual C++ you can use search&replace with regular expression:

Replace

"{#include.*}"

with

"\0\nusing namespace std;class string;struct{void htestfunc(void){typedef string htesttype;}};"

in the whole project.

Comment: `<string.h>` is a C header.  You're probably talking about `<string>`.

Comment: That is nicely platform independent, but frighteningly labor intensive to doctor every #include.  Fiendishly clever, emphasis on the fiendish.